# JBoss 7.1.1 with Hibernate 4.1.1

Tags: hibernate-mapping, jboss7.x

I was developing Application which will read the Hibernate configuration from hibernate.cfg.xml file which is under following folder

JBoss7.1.1/standalone/configuration/example1/hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping resource="example1/hbm/T1.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="example1/hbm/T2.hbm.xml"/>
```

and all the mapping file are kept under
JBoss7.1.1/standalone/configuration/example1/hbm/*.hbm.xml

But its not working, its throwing

org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource:example1/hbm/T1.hbm.xml.

is their any issue with the above configuration? am i missing somethning.

Answer (score 1):

That directory is not in your class path. You need to put the configuration some where in your application class path.